# Modifying Spree models to add more relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models, spree

I created new models in my app which is using spree. I have a new model called lets say `Something` and I want to spree `Product` to have an one to many relationship with Something. So I added a folder in apps directory called `spree` and model called `product.rb` and the code inside it is

```
module Spree
  class Product < Spree::Base
    extend FriendlyId

    has_many :somethings
  end
end
```

If I run my console, my products have access to something but all other default spree product methods are not. I think I overriden them. What is the mistake I am doing? I wanna `open` the spree products class and add my new associations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gotta monkeypatch that thing!

**#{Rails.root}/lib/extensions/spree/product.rb**

```
Spree::Product.class_eval do |variable|
  has_many :somethings , class_name: Something ,:foreign_key => "something_id" 
end
```

**/#{Rails.root}/config/application.rb**

```rb
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/extensions)
```

Comment: Thanks. After some more digging in, I found the following link(http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/logic.html#extending-classes) in spree guide for customising models.

Comment: Thanks @I-am-batman.  Any chance you can mark this as accepted answer cuz after looking it would seem I'm saying the same thing the spree docs would have you do.  No?

Answer (score -1):

Spree is a rails engine (more about [rails engines here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html)).

It means whatever class you re-implement in your application, that version will take over the original.

What I would suggest is:

1. Find out where your spree gem is located:

   gem which spree
2. Go to app/models/spree and open product.rb. Copy the whole class content and paste it into your own class.
3. Update the class file with the new feature aditions, like

   has_many :somethings

Comment: I would not recommend this method.  It will make your update-path with Spree gem very frail.  Also, it will not be clear what exactly has been changed.  Please see my monkeypatch answer!

Comment: @DarrenHicks monkey patching is a kind of advanced topic for someone just starting with rails and engines as this seems to be the case.

Comment: Well, then it's a good time for them to start building good habits :)

Comment: Maybe. Meta-programming is a whole new topic, and sometimes people just need a good answer to be able to move on.

Comment: He actually was trying to re-open the class.  I told him the correct way to do what he wanted to do.  "I wanna open the spree products class and add my new associations."  He was perplexed as to why his re-opening the class wasn't working.  Please find better things to be nit-picky about...